# SocketTimeOut Exception using Struts 2 and Apache commons-fileupload

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, struts2, java-io

I want to post a picture to my server(tomcat 7.0.40).
And the project is built on apache-struts2-2.2.1 and spring 3.6 and apache-commons-fileupload.
First, I do some html code.

```jsp
<input type="file" name="xxx" id="ccc" />
```

OK,next. I make an action extends `ActionSupport`.

```java
public XxxAction extends ActionSupport{
    private java.io.File xxx;
    public String execute() throws Exception{
        ......
    }
    //getter and setter below
}
```

And next,this action injected by spring config like:

```xml
<bean id="xxxAction" class="xxx.xxx.XxxAction" />
```

May be you have found I lost `scope="prototype"`,but please ignore it, because the problem is not there.

Next, configured by `struts2.xml` like:

```xml
<package name="xxx" namespace="/xxx" extends="json-default">  
<action name="upload" class="xxxAction">    
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">  
       <param name="allowedTypes">image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpg</param>      
    </interceptor-ref>  
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>  
   <result>
       <param name="root">toFrontJson</param>
   </result>    
</action>  
</package>
```

OK,now submit a pic file to server.We assume the file can be received by action. But when the pic is large enough to passing for a moment, and half of passing I closed the web browser. It will get `SocketTimeOut` Exception. I find the `server.xml` in tomcat config folder, the connection timeout is settled to 20000. And the most important when I got this exception. Other request to this action cannot access. It will get:

`cannot find aciton or result ......`

I think the `SocketTimeOut` Excepiton must cause some things happen. It let the action instance disappear. So I add  `scope="prototype"` in `spring.xml`. It works. Although when I interrupt fileupload operation, I got some other exception，but Other request is OK.

But I hope know what happened before I add `scope="prototype"`, why other request cannot find action, and why I got `SocketTimeOut` Exception.

In apache-commons-fileupload? Or Struts 2?

Answer (score 0):

The default scope used by Spring is `singleton`. So your code is failed because of synchronization IO operation on the file.

When you changed it to `prototype` then each action has its own instance of the action bean, so they are use its own field and don't stuck on each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Could you tell me detail what happned when SocketTimeOut Exception occurred.

Comment: The socket timeout is occurred. It means that the server is sitting on the socket and waiting for the client to do something, but the client is blocked by another client. The server won't wait it anymore after the timeout exceeds.